# Resume shell script execution after text insertion in the file

Tags: macos, shell

I'm writing my own shell script for installing and setuping vagrant, and I want to write to `vvv-custom.yml` file, so that I can add my own custom site. I added in my `init.sh` file (after installing and setuping vagrant)

```
#!/bin/sh

# Other code is here

touch vvv-custom.yml;
/bin/cat > vvv-custom.yml <<- EOM
---
sites:

  # My site
  # Site is situated in www/my-site/ available at http://my-site.dev. Other sites will be multisite of the main site.
  my-site:
    hosts:
     - my-site.dev
     - site1.my-site.dev
     - site2.my-site.dev
     - site3.my-site.dev
    custom:
      wp_type: subdomain
EOM

echo "Blaaaaa"
```

What I expected to see is new file created with the contents that are between `EOM` (that happened), and then just `Blaaaaa` written out in my terminal. But instead that whole `echo "Blaaaaa"` gets written in my `vvv-custom.yml` file.

What am I doing wrong here? I'd like to provision vagrant next but this kinda messes things up.

Comment: What OS or sh version are you using? I couldn't reproduce your error

Comment: MacOS Sierra, GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin16). It's odd, when placed on its own the echo is inside the newly created file, but when I placed other code it seems to be working :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `touch` isn't doing anything useful here.

Second, you have `<<- EOM` when you should have `<<EOM`.

Comment: I'm not that skilled with shell, so `/bin/cat > file.txt` will create the file? And isn't `<<- EOM` for ignoring leading tabs?

Comment: `>file.txt` will create the file, erasing the former contents if any.  As for `<<- EOM`, why don't you try my suggestion and see if it works.

Comment: Seems to be working. Thanks. Do you know why this happened?

Comment: cat <<XXX runs until it sees "XXX".  Since you had cat <<- EOM, it was looking for "- EOM".  Which it never did.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation